# Setting PATH for whole user session

Tags: linux, environment-variables, systemd, wayland

I need to add a path from my home folder to the PATH variable for the entire user session.

I am running a Plasma session under Wayland on the Steam Deck.

Using `$HOME/.config/environment.d/***.conf` to set `PATH=mypath:$PATH` doesn't work. It works for other variables such as FOO=BAR, but not PATH. God knows why.

.xinitrc doesn't work because it's ignored by Wayland. It's a known issue.

.profile doesn't work because it's ignored by Wayland. It's a known issue.

.bashrc doesn't work because it only applies to bash and Wayland doesn't run in bash.

Using .xsession led to some kind of Xorg launch loop that required me to delete the file from a rescue image.

To save myself from future headaches I would please like the most general solution possible. Ideally systemd should update the PATH variable using a config file or script (preferably the latter) from the user's home directory whenever that user logs in anywhere. Wayland should have no opportunity to screw this up. In principle environment.d should do the job, but in the case of PATH it doesn't for some reason I cannot comprehend.

Comment: Did you `export` the path?

Comment: In the scripts, yes. Like I said, it's a known Wayland issue.